# Next JS build not working with Apostrophe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, next.js

This is running build but,

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
    
    export default function Home() {
      return (
        
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <title>Filmydom</title>
          <h1>Filmydom</h1>
          <tagline>Lets be Filmy</tagline>
          <br />
          <br />
          <h3>Coming Soon</h3>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

This is not

```
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
    
    export default function Home() {
      return (
        
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <title>Filmydom</title>
          <h1>Filmydom</h1>
          <tagline>Let's be Filmy</tagline>
          <br />
          <br />
          <h3>Coming Soon</h3>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Just because the tagline contains " ' ".

This happened when I was trying to build and deploy on firebase.

How to build with Apostrophe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `tagline` a valid HTML Element? I wonder if that could be contributing to this odd behavior.

Otherwise could try string literal:

```
export default function Home() {
      return (
        
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <title>Filmydom</title>
          <h1>Filmydom</h1>
          <tagline>{`Let's be Filmy`}</tagline>
          <br />
          <br />
          <h3>Coming Soon</h3>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Even with valid HTML elements " ' " was causing a problem but adding curly braces and backslash helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&apos;` for the Apostrophe to build successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear an error like this by replacing the apostrophe with the universal html symbol like the following:

Space ( ) is &#32

Exclamation mark (!) is &#33

Double quotation (“) is &#34

Number sign (#) is &#35

Percent sign (%) is &#37

Comma (,) is &#44

Hyphen (-) is &#45

Period (.) is &#46

Slash (/) is &#47

And of course...
Apostrophe (') is &#39

```
Example
Error prone
<p>Let's connect!</p>

Clean
<p>Let&#39;s connect!</p>
```